# Creating Cumulative Column in SAS Using PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I've seen ways to do this using code such as this:

```
 data a; 
 set a; 
 xsum + x; 
 run;
```

I would prefer to be able to do this using PROC SQL.

I have a large table with a day difference counter.  It measures multiple processes that started on the same day and tracks how long it takes for the process to terminate.  I want to add a cumulative column to this table to be able to see the overall progress of the batch of processes.  This is what I have right now:

```
proc sql;
create table work.distribution as
select unique(difference) as day_count
        ,sum(case when difference <= day_count then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as proportion
from work.day_difference
order by day_count;
quit;
```

The output is just showing a full proportion for each unique difference value.

For example:

Difference = 0 proportion = 1

Difference = 1 proportion = 1

Where it should only be showing 1 at difference = 45, when all processes have completed.

Does anybody have any ideas of tweeks that could potentially get the cumulative column to show up correctly?

Here is a data sample:

```
      init_dt  finish_dt difference
        20667   20667   0
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20668   20667   1
        20669   20667   2
        20669   20667   2
        20669   20667   2
        20669   20667   2
        20669   20667   2
        20669   20667   2
        20669   20667   2
        20669   20667   2
        20669   20667   2
```

Here is a sample of the output:

```
   day_count     proportion
    0             1
    1             1
    2             1
    3             1 
    4             1
    7             1
    8             1
    9             1
    10            1
    11            1
    14            1
    15            1
```

Comment: supply a sample of your data

Comment: I think the data step is more efficient than anything you can do with native `proc sql`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think you are right.  I've been doing some more research and haven't found anything that makes sense over the data step.